# Basin code in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, java, hydrology, watershed, basin

How to find 6digit in HYBAS_ID of "WWF HydroSHEDS Basins Level 7" database.
Technical Documentation says that:

> Next 6 digits represent a unique identifier within the HydroSHEDS network; values larger than 900,000 represent lakes and only occur in the customized format (with lakes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the HYBAS_ID of a specific basin according to its geographic location, first add the dataset to the map:

```
var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection("WWF/HydroSHEDS/v1/Basins/hybas_7");
Map.addLayer(dataset, {}, "Basins");
```

Then click on the Inspector tab and use the cursor that appears to click on the basin of interest within the map. This will print out the object properties, including the HYBAS_ID:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful.